# sql table with 4 bool columns and 1 int column. How to add all bools from one int together

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add all true bool values from all rows AND all columns together.

My table looks like:

[image]

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM name
WHERE kw = 8 --> MO + DI + MI + DO = 10
```

That should be possible in one select, but I just don't know how.

Comment: Are you trying to get records where kw = 8 and the other columns are true/1?

Comment: KM= 8 and whats the other condition? Others have to be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the values together for each record, and then use an aggregate to sum the rows.  Since they are Boolean values adding zero will not effect the summed result.

```
SELECT sum(MO+DI+MI+DO) myResult
FROM name
where kw = 8
```

If you need a data set grouped by each kw... you could do it this way as well... it would be better performance than querying by each kw individually.

```
SELECT kw, sum(MO+DI+MI+DO) myResult
FROM name
GROUP BY kw
```

Comment: You could add kw to the select and group by it to return multiple records as well if needed.

Answer (score 0):

to view

```
SELECT (MO<<3) + (DI<<2) + (MI <<1) + (DO <<0);
```

to udpate

```
UPDATE table set KW = (MO<<3) + (DI<<2) + (MI <<1) + (DO <<0);
```

Comment: i dont uderstand why i need an update but have the solution from xqubert. if you want to explain it to me do that but i know how it works now.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i am nor correct understand quer question first. first i understand that you want to sum each row with a unique value